# Length of float integer in Python

Tags: python

I am unable to understand the actual memory space that is allocated to integers and floats in python.

From what I know, sizes of int and float variables by default in python are 32-bit and 64-bit respectively.

But from results of the following code, it looks like 28-bits and 24-bits are allocated.

```
i = 2
print(sys.getsizeof(i))
```

Output: 28

```
i = 0.02
print(sys.getsizeof(i))
```

Output: 24

Please let me know what part have I misunderstood here.

Comment: Getsizeof returns the number of bytes, not bits. And they are full objects, not just a simple chunk of data.

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49318826/getting-size-of-primitive-data-types-in-python

Answer (score 0):

`getsizeof` actually returns you the amount of *bytes* of an object - in Python both floats, ints and every other object is a full fledged object: there are no "naked" CPU primitives.

That account for most of the performance hits Python has when compared with similar mixed bytecode-interpreted languages, when benchmarking.

That said, Python floats are, indeed, internally 64 bit floats, and Python INTs are special unlimited objects which are stored internally in base-256 and are variable length featuring arbitrary precision